# Camel (audit)log to somewhere e.g. into elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel, audit-logging

There are many ways to log info with camel

- .log -dsl
- .to("log: ")
- .wireTap("direct:myLogRoute")
- .process(customLogProcessor)

All this can be mixed of course. On the other hand i have some requirements about logging:

- log into an elastic search instance (http/rest, no problem to integrated with camel)
- log the "MessageHistory" and some selected bodies and headers (at least incoming and outgoing and some intermediate)
- minimize "pollution" of routes with statements like (log, wiretap etc)
- minimize write access to elastic search or the cache in between -> one, probably big entry per exchanged handled

**So what would be a good way to achieve all this (don't know if all are good ideas)?**

Ideas that came to my mind:

- override DefaultMessageHistory and enrich it with payload/header data for some selected nodes (or all nodes) - how to override DefaultMassageHistory?
- define an interceptor that intercepts selected nodes and collects information (as separate property?) to be "logged" at the end

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I hope there is a pattern or a set of pattern to be used here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple solution would be calling a route inside `onCompletion` callback. In that route use a bean to transform your Exchange into a suitable string then POST to REST endpoint

Comment: this is a nice idea indeed. The only problem remaining is how to save some intermediate bodies (is there also a solution out of the route?). I want to post the MessageHistory and some payloads.

Comment: I have the same requirement and ended up lugging around a custom "transaction summary" instance as an exchange property. My processors are responsible to augment the summary with all required intermediary results, states, etc. I use an `onCompletion` route to asynchronously send the transaction summary to our audit system.

Comment: In our setup, we use the standard `.log(...)` DSL that simply log in local files and then we use a [log4j plugin](https://github.com/ryantenney/log4j-redis-appender) to sends also the log in a Redis DB (buffer before the ELK stack).